# Changing the position of a view while user scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I have a long screen and I use `NestedScrollView` and a `RecyclerView` with it like the below screen:

[image]

As you see I have a `commentConatiner` layout at the bottom of the screen, currently the user sees it when they scroll to the bottom.

But, I need the user to see the `commentConatiner` when they open the screen at the bottom of the screen; and when the user scrolls, the `commentConatiner` view should move with the scroll until the `ScrollView` reaches to the `commentConatiner` position.

I mean it should be shown all the times (at the bottom) and when user scroll the screen, it should move with scroll until it reaches to its normal position.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/commentConatiner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="26dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvChat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:itemCount="1"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_discussion" />


                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/noDataContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_comma_green"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvNoData"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvNoData" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNoData"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                        android:text="@string/there_is_no_discussion"
                        android:textColor="@color/kafd_color_blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/x13sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentConatiner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_white_bg"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etComment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/x8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:hint="@string/write_here"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/kafd_color_gray_1"
            android:textColorHint="@color/kafd_color_gray_1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/x14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rvSelectedFiles"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivFile"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rvSelectedFiles"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_attachment"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivSend"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivSend"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivSend" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvSelectedFiles"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivSend"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etComment"
            app:spanCount="2"
            tools:itemCount="4"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_selected_attachment" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: From what I understood you want the comment section to be always visible when the users open that page. and even if they scrolled it has to be visible? right.

Comment: Yes but when it be visible , it should not hide the views

Comment: It should has his position at the bottom of the screen , but it should be visible at the bottom of the screen and when user scroll the scree , the comment container should return to its position

Comment: okay. let me work on a solution. you don't have to have a nested scroll view

Comment: I need the nested scroll view in my layout because this layout is for a fragment and this fragment is in ViewPager

Comment: its a floating comment section?, 

I get why you need the nested

Comment: this might help check it.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout

Comment: I use the CoordinateLayout with the toolbar

Comment: okay? did it work

Comment: it's working with toolbar but my problem not related with this

Comment: I see, I tired a solution but didn't work with me

Comment: I asked on Chat GPT also but it didn't help me

Comment: try it with toolbar if it does work with it

Comment: CoordinatorLayout is not make it appear all time , it make it appear when I scroll and it hide views , I can fix the hiding of the views but I want to make it all time appear at bottom

Comment: Okay you need to place the comment container in the bottom static but when we scroll it should also scroll but should not go out of the view if it reaches the bottom it should not placed static. Like sticky header.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the `commentContainer` visible at the bottom of the screen and having it move with the scroll until it reaches its normal position, you can make the following adjustments to your XML layout:

1. Move the `commentContainer` outside the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and the `NestedScrollView`.
2. Use a `RelativeLayout` as the root layout to simplify positioning.
3. Set appropriate constraints for the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, `NestedScrollView`, and the `commentContainer`.

**Example of modified XML layout:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- Your existing NestedScrollView content here -->

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_white_bg"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <!-- Your existing commentContainer content here -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's not working , the comment container is hiding the views and not appear at the bottom when I open the screen